# Updating Data between two components in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React and I don't know what's the best way to do this.

I have a list of cars and on clicking each row it should show slide to full page details of that car.

My code structure is:

I have App which renders two components. CarList and CarDetails. Car Details is hidden initially. The reason I rendered carDetails in app is because it's a massive fix template so I would like to render this once when app is loaded and only update it's data when each row clicked.

CarList also renders CarRow component which is fine.
Now my problem is I have a getDetails function on CarRow component which is making a call to get the details based on the car id. How to get carDetails component data updated ? I used 
    this.setState({itemDetails:data});
but seems state of the carRow is not the same reference as state in carDetails.

Any help?

Answer (score 2):

This is a fundamental issue that lots of thought and man-hours has gone into in order to try and solve. It probably can't be answered, except on a surface level, in a StackOverflow post. It's not React-centric, either. This is an issue across most applications, regardless of the framework you're using.

Since you asked in the context of React, you might consider reading into [flux](https://facebook.github.io/flux/), which is the de-facto implementation of this one-way data-flow idea in concert with React. However, that architecture is by no means "the best". There are simply advantages and disadvantages to it like everything else.

Some people don't like the idea of the global "event bus" that flux proposes. If that's the case, you can simply implement your own intermediate data layer API that collects query callbacks and A) invokes the callbacks on any calls to save data and B) refreshes any appropriate queries to the server. For now, though, I'd stick with flux as it will give you an idea of the general principles involved in having the things that most people consider to be "good", like a single source of truth for your data, one way flow, etc.

To give a concrete example of the callback idea:

```
// data layer

const listeners = [];

const data = {
  save: save,
  query: query
};

function save(someData) {
  // save data to the server, and then...
  .then(data => {
    listeners.forEach(listener => listener(data));
  }); 
}

function query(params, callback) {
  // query the server with the params, then
  listeners.push(callback);
}

// component

componentWillMount() {
  data.query(params, data => this.setState({ myData: data }));
},

save() {
  // when the save operation is complete, it will "refresh" the query above
  data.save(someData);
}
```

This is a very distilled example and doesn't address optimization, such as potential for memory leaks when moving to different views and invoking "stale" callbacks, however it should give you a general idea of another approach.

The two approaches have the same policy (a single source of truth for data and one way data flow) but different implementations (global "event bus" which necessitates keeping track of events, or the simple callback method, which can necessitate a form of memory management).